# Using Multiple Wildcards with -like Operator

Tags: powershell, wildcard, netsh

I'm attempting to parse the output of `netsh winhttp show proxy` to ensure the correct proxy settings have been applied with my script. To start, this is the expected output of the command:

```
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Proxy Server(s) :  proxy.website.com:8080
    Bypass List     :  *.example1.com;*.sample-site.com;
```

Below is a cut down version of what I'm doing. The if statement is evaluating to false when it should be true (I know the proxy settings are correct before running). I'm suspecting there's an issue with how I'm utilizing multiple wildcards with the `-like` operator, as evaluating only `$ProxyServer` or `$BypassListEscaped` on their own work, but I'm not sure. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
$NetshOutput = (netsh winhttp show proxy)

$ProxyServer = "proxy.website.com:8080"
$ProxyBypass = "*.example1.com;*.sample-site.com;"

$BypassListEscaped = $ProxyBypass.Replace("*", "``*").Replace("`"", "")

if ($NetshOutput -like "*$ProxyServer*$BypassListEscaped*"){
    Write-Host "correct"
}else{
    Write-Host "incorrect"
}
```

Comment: you're pretty much suffering from the same issue as in your previous question :). join the output from your command so it becomes a single string instead of an array of strings: `$NetshOutput = (netsh winhttp show proxy) -join [environment]::NewLine`

Answer (score 0):

Output from `netsh` command is an array of strings, you need to convert that array into a single string before your comparison. You can also use [`WildcardPattern.Escape` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern.escape?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) for escaping wildcard characters.

```bash
$NetshOutput = (netsh winhttp show proxy) -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
$ProxyServer = 'proxy.website.com:8080'
$ProxyBypass = [WildcardPattern]::Escape('*.example1.com;*.sample-site.com;')

if($NetshOutput -like "*$ProxyServer*$ProxyBypass*") {
    Write-Host 'correct'
}
else {
    Write-Host 'incorrect'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$output = netsh winhttp show proxy
$output -like "*Proxy Server:*" **-and** $output -like ""

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).